# Define a function in bash and pass it to a .run script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to install VirtualBox on a Linux system. When running the installer, I run into an error due to not having bzip2 on this system:

```
# bash -i VirtualBox-5.2.16-123759-Linux_x86.run 
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox for Linux installation.............
VirtualBox Version 5.2.16 r123759 (2018-07-16T15:17:42Z) installer
Removing previous installation of VirtualBox 5.2.16 r123759 from 
/opt/VirtualBox
Installing VirtualBox to /opt/VirtualBox
./install.sh: line 252: bzip2: command not found
```

Unfortunately for me, I cannot get bzip2 installed on this system. However, I do have tar with the bzip2 support (the "j" flag). I cannot modify the .run file to use tar instead of bzip2, however.

So, my new idea is to use a function in bash, something along these lines:

```
function bzip2() { ... use tar to extract the bz2 file in a way that's compliant with the use case in the .run file ... }
```

A simple test, however, shows I cannot get the bzip2 function to be used in the .run file:

```
# bzip2() { echo $1; }
# bzip2 test
test
# bash -i VirtualBox-5.2.16-123759-Linux_x86.run 
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox for Linux installation.............
VirtualBox Version 5.2.16 r123759 (2018-07-16T15:17:42Z) installer
Removing previous installation of VirtualBox 5.2.16 r123759 from /opt/VirtualBox
Installing VirtualBox to /opt/VirtualBox
./install.sh: line 252: bzip2: command not found
```

Comment: You *do* know that passing `-j` to `tar` makes it delegate to the `bzip2` executable, right?

Answer (score 1):

Functions are not exported into child processes by default. From [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions):

> Functions may be exported so that subshells automatically have them
>   defined with the `-f` option to the `export` builtin.

```
$ cat script 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
greet
$ greet() { echo hello; }
$ ./script
./script: line 2: greet: command not found
$ export -f greet
$ ./script
hello
```